# How can I display a list of child categories on a category page?

Tags: wordpress

There is a category page.
How do I list links to its child categories?

```
<h1>This page category Test</h1>
echo ...; // links all child category for Test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get current viewing category id and taxonomy name. For that you need to call get_queried_object() this function like below:

```
$term = get_queried_object();
```

Then you need to call the get_terms() function to get child categories like below:

```
$child_categories = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
    'parent'    => $term->term_id,
    'hide_empty' => false
) );

if ( !empty( $child_categories ) ) { 
    foreach( $child_categories as $c_cat ) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $c_cat, $c_cat->taxonomy ) ) . '">' . $c_cat->name . '</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: + and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47097940/wp-list-categories-display-first-level-categories-and-only-current-terms-ch